# Alert Blocking Segue-iOS

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertcontroller

I want to ask the user for permission (for which I am using UIAlert) before performing the segue. Once they have answered the question in the alert, I want to segue to the next View Controller, irrespective of their answer.

The code looks something like this:

```
showAlert()        //Method showing the alert

performSegue(withIdentifier : "secondVC", sender : self)
```

The problem I am facing here is that the app is showing me the alert but not performing the segue.

Comment: You need to pass a completion handler closure to your `showAlert` function. Have that function invoke the closure from the action handler on the alert view. In the closure you can perform the segue

Comment: Can you post your showAlert() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a completion handler to your alert's dismiss button like this

```swift
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Content Here", preferredStyle: .alert)

// add textfield or whatever you need

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondVC", sender: self)
}))
present(alert, animated: true)
```

The completion handler will be called when the user presses the "OK" button on the alert.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! this is what I ended up using. I wanted to avoid the completion handler at first because I was using a function to set up the alert and then doing more checks before the segue but then just changed the function to do all the checks instead.